# Suggested edit flag isn't clearing, even there isn't anything for me to review in the queue

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, reviewing

I came to the site this morning and saw the flag notice for a new suggested edit.  I clicked the flag, looked at the suggested edit, and skipped it (because I didn't know anything about the game in question).  Now normally for me this doesn't clear the flag for me, it's only after going back to the review queues or front page that it disappears, but this time, even after completing a number of other review tasks, going to the front page, etc., it still hasn't cleared for me.  Clicking on it just takes me to the "**There are no items for you to review**" page.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: I don't think it's caching, because I did a forced reload and it still didn't go away.  But, just to appease you, I cleared my cache for today, and it's still there.

Comment: There's something funky going on with SE today; the little red indicator for responses isn't clearing for me.  I suspect this may be the same issue.

Comment: That actually is working for me - when it decides to show up (I still haven't been informed of rep I got yesterday).

Comment: Oh wait, nevermind.  It was just being a tease.  It disappears and then shows up again when I go to another page.

Comment: (Server-side caching is also a thing. Stuck notifications are happening all the time when they do the read-only tests, god knows why.)